# How to specify the max of a field +1 when defining a SetField value in a Before Insert trigger?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a database with a table that has as its primary key an autoincrement number field I call `id`.

In the datasheet view, I want to create some new records using cut/paste of some existing records, then update/modify those records. The paste doesn't work because the `id` values of the cut records already exist and `id` is a primary key.

I want to set the value for `id` to be the `max(id)+1` *before* the insert to avoid the conflict.

I tried to do this with a trigger (using the `Before Change` event). But I don't know how to specify `max(id)+1`.

I tried `max([id])+1` and `max([id+1])`, no luck. I also tried to stuff a SQL statement in there, something like `select max(id)+1 from thetable`. That didn't work.

Does anyone know how to specify `max(id)+1` in MS Access lingo such that this might work?  I don't think `max` is a built-in that Access knows about.

Is this a fool's errand? Can this be made to work?

Is there a better way to approach this, maybe with VBA?

Finally, is there a way to stuff a SQL expression in the value field?

I noticed that MS Access supports `Before Change` and `Before Delete`, but not `Before Insert`. Is there the equivalent of a `Before Insert` trigger for this database?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your table a local or link table?  I just tried it on a local table and the AutoNumber ID field automatically increments when I copy-pasted the same rows including its ID field.

Comment: Why would you 'cut/paste', did you mean 'copy/paste'? Is this 'autoincrement' an Autonumber type field? If so, copy/paste works fine on a local or link table. If this is not Autonumber, then how are you generating this ID?

Comment: Change = Insert and update. If you want specific behavior before inserting, use a `Before Change` trigger, and the `IsInsert` constant to test if the change is an insert. See [the docs on Before Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/before-change-macro-event)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access data macro get value from query (auto numbering)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873857/access-data-macro-get-value-from-query-auto-numbering)

Comment: It's just a table I created in a MS-Access DB.  It didn't link to anything, so I guess it's "local" ?
 
Yes, copy/paste (sorry).
 
No, it wasn't an autonumber, but I thought it was.  I changed that and this works now.  Looks like I needed that slap upside the head to wake me up to checking this.  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Using the "Before Change" event you can set the value as

DMax("[Id]","[YourTableName]")+1

This will work